# how change icon marker in gmap.net in c#.net

Tags: c#, google-maps

i am write code for in each for loop one on other icon marker but for all maker last icon marker.

```
str_id = ds_picture.Tables["tbl"].Rows[0][1].ToString();

GapMarkerGoogle_MarkerActiev[] marker=new GapMarkerGoogle_MarkerActiev[200];
```

in the for loop

```
SqlDataAdapter da_picture2 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Mobile_Gps_Pictures where id=" + str_id + "", con_map_GPS);
DataSet ds_picture2 = new DataSet();
da_picture2.Fill(ds_picture2, "tbl");

Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(GoogleMap.Properties.Resources._4shanbe);
if (bmp != null)
{
    bmp.Dispose();
}
try
{
    Byte[] byteBLOBData = new Byte[0];
    byteBLOBData = (Byte[])(ds_picture2.Tables["tbl"].Rows[0][1]);
    bmp = new Bitmap(ByteToImage(byteBLOBData));

}
catch
{

}
marker[i] = new GapMarkerGoogle_MarkerActiev(new PointLatLng(p2, p1), bmp);
markersOverlay.Markers.Add(marker[i]);

gMapControl1.Overlays.Add(markersOverlay);
```